# Using Chernoff's inequality to give a bound on a probability given the MGF

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Let $G$ be a $\text{Gamma}(k,2)$ random variable. Its MGF is
>   $\left(1-\frac{t}{2}\right)^{-k}$ for $t < 2$. Using Chernoff's inequality, give
>   a bound on the probability, $$P(G > 1)$$

**My attempt:**

$$P(G > 1) = P\left(e^{tX} \ge e^{t}\right)\le\frac{E\left[e^{tX}\right]}{e^{t}}$$
by Chernoff's bound. $E[e^{tX}] = MGF = (1-\frac{t}{2})^{-k}$ so we have

$$P(G > 1) \le \frac{(1-\frac{t}{2})^{-k}}{e^{t}}$$

From here I'm not sure what to do next, do I just leave it as this or is there more that needs to be done? if anyone can help me with this that would be really appreciated.

Comment: $t$ is still arbitrary, so you may try to minimize the term with respect to $t$ in the proper range.

Comment: It depends on $k$. The term $(1-\frac{t}2)^{-k}e^{-t}$ is defined for $t<2$, so you could calculate its maximum and obtain a bound independent of $t$, but it depends on $k$.

Comment: @Stef, I think you mean calculate its *minimum*

Comment: @MarcusM I am thinking of something like $E\left[e^{tX}\right] \le \frac{(1-\frac{t}{2})^{-k}}{e^{t}}\le \sup_{t<2}{\left\{\frac{(1-\frac{t}{2})^{-k}}{e^{t}}\right\}}$

Comment: @Stef, I think that's the wrong kind of idea.  You don't need to bound $E[e^{tX}]e^{-t}$, you need to bound $P(G > 1)$.  Since $P(G > 1) \leq E[e^{tX}] e^{-t}$ **for every $t$**, you just have to choose the $t$ that gives the best upper bound, i.e. the lowest value.

Comment: @MarcusM It seems correct, I will go with the minimum.